# Simple CSS assistance

Tags: css, flexbox

I need my elements be in one row, centered by height and have right horizontal align in bounded block. I tried to use flexbox for that and everything works great only for one line items, otherwise overflowed element take all available space and it does not look right aligned.

```css
.flex {
  width:80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
span {  
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <i>0</i>
  <span>
    good 
  </span>
</div><br>
<div class="flex">
  <i>0 </i>
  <span>
    Not that good
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the width? Probably the text Not that good is to long for a Width of 80 and so flexbox adds some linebreaks.

Comment: I can't remove width, the outher div is bounded to some width, and yes 'Not that good'  is too long for that width and I want it to break into lines but I also want 'Not that good' not to take extra space in div so  whole block would look right aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the flex attributes onto the container so that the items (your divs) get aligned. Here you can see a working solution:

[Flexbox](https://jsfiddle.net/6dewcaf5/)

Your container will have the following css attributes and is a simple div.

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

I really like the Guide for Flexbox that you can find [HERE](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). IT helped me a lot on understanding the flexbox specific modifiers.

Comment: Thanks for helping but sitll  '0' character insde the '.flex' block is not right aligned. Css proprety 'flex-basis' helped a bit but it's behavior is not perfect

Comment: Add the css attribute flex-direction: row; to your .flex class. After that it should place the 0 exactly beside the not so good, but there is still some space between the right edge, and this is because of the line wrapping from Not So good. If you remove all the whitespaces it should work properly, but i guess you do not want to remove them.